# What would be a good alternate for the SugarCRM email databse?

Tags: email, sugarcrm

My company has between 50,000 - 100,000 contacts that is currently being managed in excel. The director of marketing wants an email database to work in junction with Microsoft Exchange and our budget is $5,000 for the program.

SugarCRM seems great but what other programs are comparable?

Answer (score 0):

When you say works with Microsoft Exchange, I take it you mean that you want something that can send through it rather than something that integrates with it (If I am wrong, please say).

I recommend [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com/), I have some clients that have 250,000+ people on a list and send through an Exchange SMTP server and this works very well and has quite a few nice additional features that are brilliant when running such a highly subscribed list.

Comment: You assume correctly Wil. I'm no IT guy, so I've been talking to my IT friends while wearing my (funky looking) IT hat.

I will check out PHPList. Thank you for your reply.

Those others reading this, please list additional suggestions as we are still weighing our options :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Tactile CRM](http://www.tactilecrm.com/signup2). It's a web-app that claims to work with an umlimited number of contacts. The integration with Exchange is not that great, however it does have other benefits depending on what you are looking for.